# why I can't no longer install my app after I factory reset my Mac?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have apple developer account. before I factory reset my Mac, I can install my app through cable data directly from My Mac to my iPhone (not via .ipa).

but after I factory reset my Mac, I can no longer install my app through cable data. The app is actually installed to my iPhone, but after I press the Icon, the app will immadiatelly close.

what should I do ? I suspect it relates to provisioning profile, certificate etc....I don't really understand about these things.

because of that,I have to install my app to the iPhone by generating the ipa file which is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You should regenerate your developer certificate and provisioning in your mac.this is Signing workflow:
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev60b6fbbc7

Answer (score 0):

The app is probably not being signed correctly. Most likely, the factory reset removed your private key for a build certificate. To make it work again, you would need to create a new certificate+key pair, which you can do directly from Xcode.

This link has more info: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev154b28f09. Follow the "Create a signing certificate" steps.